# Escape + (plus) in URI

Tags: .net, urlencode, url-encoding

When user enters an e-mail on my web site, I send an e-mail verification e-mail that contains a link. Link looks something like:

http://mysite.com/VerifyEmail?email=name@domain.com&token=12341234

This particular user's e-mail contains '+' (plus), so link looks like:

http://mysite.com/VerifyEmail?email=foo+bar@domain.com&token=12341234

when link is clicked (at least in Firefox) plus is replaced with a space.

**Question:** What URL encoding function do I use in .net to escape the plus.

Note: `Uri.EscapeUriString(email)` leaves plus intact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) instead - I've just verified that that converts "Foo+Bar" into "Foo%2BBar".

To be honest, I'd appreciate it if MS provided a little more guidance on the difference between these methods, as well as `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` (which isn't available on all platforms).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) method:

```
string encodedEmail = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to hash or encrypt the e-mail address, or somewhat "include" it on your token.

That way, your link can look like:
http://mysite.com/VerifyEmail?token=12341234480348204023

Or:
http://mysite.com/VerifyEmail?emailcode=A124E4F325O425FE5F4J6636K66L&token=12341234

If you follow the hash route, remember that Base64 also uses `+` as a valid character when encoding. The common practice is to replace it by an @ or something else:

```
var emailcode = Convert.ToBase64String(GetHashBytes(email)).Replace('+', '@');
```

Then, when you perform the confirmation:

```
var emailcodebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Request["code"].Replace('@', '+'));
```

Comment: I think that code example is slightly wrong? The first `)` is in the wrong place: `var emailcodebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Request["code"].Replace('@', '+'));`